# v-list-item-title joining with router link in App.vue

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

Is there any other way to write this line of code below for better UI interaction?

```
<v-list-item>
<v-list-item-title>
<router-link to="historicalFigures">Historical Figures </router-link>
</v-list-item-title>
</v-list-item>
```

*Im asking this because using the above code, only when i click the link of the navigation bar the results displays. 
like so*

[image]

*but when i click the area that's around the link,nothing is showing or responding.*

Answer (score 1):

Try placing a 'to' prop on a v-list-item and not nest a router link as your code is written.  Alternatively, you can use a @click on the v-list-item and that method would use this.$router.push('/historicalFigures')

```
<v-list-item to='historicalFigures'>
    <v-list-item-title>Historical Figures</v-list-item-title>
</v-list-item>
```

Answer (score 1):

In the above example, to should be bound using :to making it

```
<v-list-item :to='historicalFigures'>
    <v-list-item-title>Historical Figures</v-list-item-title>
</v-list-item>
```